# Can Flux of Project Reactor process messages one by one

Tags: project-reactor, reactor

I'm trying to process a list of numbers, for example, 1 to 10, one by one using Reactor Flux, and there is an API **/double** which simply double the incoming **Integer** (1 -> 2, 4 -> 8...) ,however this API has performance issue, it always takes 2 seconds to response the result.
When using `limitRate(1)` what I expected is Reactor processes requests one after another as following:

```
2020-01-01 00:00:02 - 2
2020-01-01 00:00:04 - 4
2020-01-01 00:00:06 - 6
2020-01-01 00:00:08 - 8
2020-01-01 00:00:10 - 10
...
```

But actually Reactor fires all requests at once:

```
2020-01-01 00:00:02 - 6
2020-01-01 00:00:02 - 10
2020-01-01 00:00:02 - 2
2020-01-01 00:00:02 - 4
2020-01-01 00:00:02 - 8
...
```

Here is the code

```
Flux.range(1, 10).limitRate(1)
                .flatMap(i -> webClient.get().uri("http://localhost:10001/double?integer={int}", i).exchange()
                        .flatMap(resp -> resp.bodyToMono(Integer.class)))
                .subscribe(System.out::println);
Thread.sleep(10000);
```

Seems `limitRate` is not working as I expected, what went wrong? Is there any way to process requests one after another using Reactor? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7):

`.flatMap` doesn't work here as it subscribes to the inner streams eagerly - that is, it won't wait for an inner stream to emit an `onComplete` before subscribing to the next stream. This is why all of your calls are made concurrently. It works in the `receive->dispatch->receive->dispatch` mode.

Reactor provides an overloaded version of `flatMap` where you can specify the concurrency factor as `.flatMap(innerstream, concurrency)`. This factor caps the number of streams flatMap will subscribe to. If it is say 5, flatMap can subscribe to at most 5 inner streams. As soon as this limit is hit, it *has* to wait for an inner stream to emit `onComplete` before it subscribes to the next one.

In your case, you can either set it to 1 or use `.concatMap()`. `concatMap()` is exactly flatMap with `concurrency = 1`. It'll basically works in the `receive->dispatch->wait->receive->dispatch->wait` mode.

I wrote a post some time back explaining exactly how `flatMap` works, because I think a lot of people use it without understanding its internals. You can refer to the article  [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=reactor%20flatmap&oq=reactor%20flatmap&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j0l4j69i60l2j69i61.1639j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Answer (score 3):

Consider to use a `concatMap` instead:

```
/**
 * Transform the elements emitted by this {@link Flux} asynchronously into Publishers,
 * then flatten these inner publishers into a single {@link Flux}, sequentially and
 * preserving order using concatenation.
 * <p>
 * There are three dimensions to this operator that can be compared with
 * {@link #flatMap(Function) flatMap} and {@link #flatMapSequential(Function) flatMapSequential}:
 * <ul>
 *     <li><b>Generation of inners and subscription</b>: this operator waits for one
 *     inner to complete before generating the next one and subscribing to it.</li>
 *     <li><b>Ordering of the flattened values</b>: this operator naturally preserves
 *     the same order as the source elements, concatenating the inners from each source
 *     element sequentially.</li>
 *     <li><b>Interleaving</b>: this operator does not let values from different inners
 *     interleave (concatenation).</li>
 * </ul>
 *
 * <p>
 * Errors will immediately short circuit current concat backlog.
 *
 * <p>
 * <img class="marble" src="doc-files/marbles/concatMap.svg" alt="">
 *
 * @reactor.discard This operator discards elements it internally queued for backpressure upon cancellation.
 *
 * @param mapper the function to transform this sequence of T into concatenated sequences of V
 * @param <V> the produced concatenated type
 *
 * @return a concatenated {@link Flux}
 */
public final <V> Flux<V> concatMap(Function<? super T, ? extends Publisher<? extends V>>
        mapper) {
```

Pay attention to the `sequentially and preserving order using concatenation.` phrase. Seems for me what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by Artem Bilan's answer, I found `flatMapSequential` is a better for my case, since the `flatMapSequential` accepts second parameter as `maxConcurrency`, so that it is possible not to process messages one by one but twice a time and etc.
Thanks Artem Bilan and Prashant Pandey for your answers, really helped.

Comment: flatMap also accepts a second parameter, sequential is unnecessary in most of the cases